# Using Systemtap probing Getting the virtual address location of bytes for every read write operation in Linux

Tags: memory, io, virtual-memory, systemtap

Using Systemtap probing tool I got the way to get total amount of bytes read by a file by probing syscall.read and syscall.read.return function.
syscall.read.return has returnval() which gives the total amount of byte read. I need to get the virtual addresses of the bytes for every read and write operation. How can I achieve this using Systemtap probing tool in linux.

Comment: You probably have to dive into ftrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SystemTap script would allow you to get the read bytes as an string:

```
probe syscall.read.return
{
  printf("writen_bytes_as_a_string=%s\n", user_string_n(@entry($buf),$return))
}
```